# How to set the performance of Event Handling in JavaScript (e.g. onmousemove) on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, mouseevent, onmousemove

**Context:** I am developing a game using the HTML5 Canvas and Javascript. I use JS's timeout functions to redraw the canvas or parts of it once every 20ms. One of the game's main mechanics is updating the client mouse position, as the player follows it. To do so, I make use of the onmousemove event.

**Behavior:** on other browsers, or on Mozilla Firefox when the computer has good processing power, I have no issues to update the mouse position, and the onmousemove event fires as frequently as the game's FPS.

**Issue:** on some of my player's computers, when they are using Mozilla Firefox, the mouse position doesn't update as frequently. They reported laggy behavior of the mouse's position, although the rest of the game keeps updating as frequently as before.

**What I discovered so far:** I tried to replicate the issue on my computer by printing the game's framerate on the console every frame. I got the same laggy behavior of the mouse as reported. What is strange is, although the framerate doesn't drop at any time, the mouse update frequency decreases the longer the page is remained open. After some minutes, onmousemove is called as rarely as once a second, but the FPS keeps high.

Is there any way of controlling how frequently Firefox fires the onmousemove event? If not, why does it stop reporting the event as time passes, but keep running my timeout functions and maintaining the FPS high? What could I do to stop the issue from happening?

EDIT:
Here is some code to help understand the issue. To handle the mouse movement:

```
const MouseHandler = function(){
  var mouseX = 0;
  var mouseY = 0;
  ...

  return {
    ...
    onMouseMove: function(){
      mouseX = window.event.clientX - bodyMargin - WIDTH/2;
      mouseY = -(window.event.clientY - bodyMargin - HEIGHT/2);
    },
    ...
  }
}();

fgCanvas.onmousemove = MouseHandler.onMouseMove;
```

And, to make the code run repeatedly:

```
const run = function(){
    intervalID = setTimeout(run, FRAME_DELAY);
    ...
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      ...
      draw[gameState]();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell when you don't share any code. Depending on your implementation throttle or denounce might be an option in combination with mousemove

Comment: You might want to switch your timeout with [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and store the latest `Event` object of the `mousemove` event in a variable that you use you loop. Include the relevant part of your code so we can check with you. And short answer, no you have no control on how frequently a browser fires an event.

Comment: I added the code snippets as asked :)